# Azure deployment The value of deployment parameter 'dockerRegistryUrl' is null

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-container-registry

Trying to deploy a web app using docker-compose and azure container registry and some public images but when I get to the review it gives me this error.

> The value of deployment parameter 'dockerRegistryUrl' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference. See https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for details.

here is how I'm linking the azure container registry

```
    image: csym023.azurecr.io/csym023_api:latest
    ...
    image: csym023.azurecr.io/csym023_app:latest
```

think I may have set up the docker-compose file incorrectly for the azure container registry but I am not sure. the documentation link isn't very clear to me it doesn't say anything about the 'dockerRegistryUrl' or where to upload the resource manager parameter file.

here is the [Docker compose file](https://pastebin.com/NBuMbiZf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, actually, the "dockerRegistryUrl" is not a property in the docker-compose file, it's an environment variable of the [Azure Web App for Container](https://gist.github.com/brbarnett/7cacd4a30bed946e9ad681c261765fbd#file-deploy-json-L70) if you use the template.

So if you use the ACR for you images, you need to set the environment variables `DOCKER-REGISTRY-SERVER-UTL`, `DOCKER-REGISTRY-SERVER-PASSWORD` and `DOCKER-REGISTRY-SERVER-USERNAME` in the app settings. Also, `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` is necessary.

In addition, you need to meet the Docker compose options which supported in Azure. And you can the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#docker-compose-options).

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not clear where I would set the environment variables for a new web application or upload a file which you linked?

Comment: would it be better to go the CLI route from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-multi-container) and just login to my container registry before creating the web application?

Comment: @AndrewDean It seems you use the Azure CLI to deploy your application, then you can use the command `az webapp config appsettings set` to set the environment variables above in the answer.

Comment: @AndrewDean What's more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: yes I have managed to fix it thanks but have run into other issues with running a privileged container (docker:dind) which ill open a new question about

Comment: @AndrewDean What is the new question? Maybe I can give you some advice.

Comment: here is the new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977249/running-public-private-images-on-azure-web-service-authentication-issue), any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: @AndrewDean OK, I'll take an eye on it.

Comment: what is DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME? i didnt set any username and password to create azure docker registery instance?