# Running public & private images on azure web service authentication issue

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

When running a mixture of private container registry images from the azure container registry and also a public image from docker.io "docker:latest" but am getting an authentication issue on the docker.io

[Docker compose file](https://pastebin.com/RzRrUu1Q)

```
    image: docker:latest
```

the issue is I only have the option to log in to one of them on the azure portal, is there a way to login into both ? or am I meant to create a new docker file in the development project which will pull and store the image on my azure container registry?

error log :

> 2019-11-21 14:07:32.273 INFO  - Pulling image: docker:latest
>
> 2019-11-21 14:07:32.959 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/docker/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password"}
>
> 2019-11-21 14:07:32.959 ERROR - Pulling docker image docker:latest failed:
>
> 2019-11-21 14:07:32.959 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: library/docker:latest
>
> 2019-11-21 14:07:34.061 INFO  - latest Pulling from library/docker
>
> 2019-11-21 14:07:34.431 INFO  -  Digest: sha256:813da205ebebb2973c7a8ecac81c49e0510e0de22bff954a0455b582a572eda2
>
> 2019-11-21 14:07:34.431 INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for docker:latest
>
> 2019-11-21 14:07:34.437 INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 1 Seconds
>
> 2019-11-21 14:07:34.464 INFO  - Starting container for site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the multiple containers on Azure Web App only support one registry currently. It means all the images must belong to one registry, no matter the ACR or Docker hub. The document I found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#MultiContainer):

> All of the images in your multi-container deployment must use the same
>   Docker registry. In other words, you can't use Azure Container
>   Registry (ACR) for one image and Docker Hub for another registry.
>   Also, if you are using ACR, all images must be on the same ACR server.

So, I recommend you could push all the images which would be used to the ACR then only use it.